# Piping commands into a console

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to pipe Windows commands into a program that essentially runs a console and I'm a newbie at this so I'm not quite getting the command right. What I want to do is pipe the command dir /b > out.txt into that other program.

The command is

> echo dir /b > out.txt | nc.exe 127.0.0.1 7003 - ignore the nc.exe its not important

What I want is to pipe the output of echo which should be "dir /b > out.txt" but I'm getting the order of operations or something wrong. Currently what happens is that I write "dir /b" into the file out.txt and pipe nothing into nc.exe.

Answer (score 2):

double quote or escape >

```
echo "dir /b > out.txt" | nc.exe 127.0.0.1 7003
```

or

```
echo dir /b ^> out.txt | nc.exe 127.0.0.1 7003
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its good enough for you.

```
echo stackoverflow.com > out.txt
nslookup<out.txt
```

Take a gander at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php